# Big Query Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm try to run a query but it is returning an error that isn't enough resources do process it.

The query is:

```
SELECT ID,
       ISNULL(LINK,'0'),
       FLOOR(ISNULL(AMOUNTPAID,'0')),
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEPAID, 5),
       PAYSOURCE 
  FROM finance 
 WHERE DATEADD(month,24,DATEPAID) > GETDATE() 
       AND ID IN (A LIST OF IDs)
```

The first select is about 1.4 million results and the list of ID's have about 100.000 ids.

Is there another way to build this query?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a long list of 100,000 `IN` values and seeing this error

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not
>   produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
>   extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
>   number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you
>   believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer
>   Support Services for more information.

Per the suggestion on [this Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/521943/the-query-processor-ran-out-of-internal-resources-and-could-not-produce-a-query-plan-with-where-in-and-several-thousand-values) put the list of Ids into a temporary table or indexed table valued parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID,ISNULL(LINK,'0'),FLOOR(ISNULL(AMOUNTPAID,'0')),CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEPAID, 5) ,PAYSOURCE 
from dbo.finance f inner join listofid l on f.id=l.id
where DATEADD(month,24,DATEPAID) > GETDATE()
```

also you need to create non-clustered index on DATEPAID.hope id is pk.
BTW, list of id is coming from where table/variable ?

i think query would be fast.you mean to say there is another query where you are putting list of id in variable.

Comment: The list of IDs was first a query, but now I'm trying the list of ID's, like this: ('10000','10010',10022', ...)

Comment: @Antonio - Why have you gone from using a query to a list of IDs? The query is the best way.

Comment: Because I have to use this ID list in 3 other queries. I did that to avoid 4 identical selects.